# Using Matrial UI grid, but Justify props is not working?

Tags: javascript, flexbox, material-ui, grid, containers

Here, justify is not working for me. any guess why?

```
  <Grid container direction='column' alignItems='center' justify='center' spacing='1'>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
       <Typography variant='h1'>Firt Item</Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
       <Typography variant='h4'>Firt Item</Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
       <Typography variant='h6'>Firt Item</Typography>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Justify props is not working"? What is the current behaviour? What is the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It's working as supposed to be. The problem is the height of the Grid component is equal to the height of its children together. As a result, changes in the `justify` value is not visible when `direction='column'`. So I set the height of the Grid component to 300px as below:

```
<Grid
      style={{ height: "300px" }}
      container
      direction="column"
      alignItems="center"
      justify="flex-end"
    >
```

to make changes visible [here in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-49wt3?file=/demo.js)